# How to accommodate all labels on Y axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlDK3.png)This is my code:

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     %matplotlib inline
     sns.scatterplot(x=df['Amount'], y=df['ship-state'],hue=df['Category'],palette='Set1')
     plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
     plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
     plt.show()
```

the image I have attached is of the plot resultant of above code, can you please tell me how can I accommodate all states on Y axis!

I tried changing size and layouts:

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

but didn't work

Comment: You really need to call `plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))` before creating the plot. Otherwise, you create a new empty plot.